# Why is macOS is unable to verify my Yahoo user ID

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, system-settings, setup, yahoo

Through System Preferences > Internet Accounts

I enter my Yahoo user ID and password and am getting error message, "unable to verify user id and password".

I have enabled POP in my Yahoo account and reset password to ensure it's accurate.

Answer (score 4):

In Apple Mail, add a new account and after entering a full name, email address and password, hold down the Option key. The Create button will change to Continue, allowing one to manually configure the account settings.

Use the following settings:

```
Incoming Server - imap.mail.yahoo.com

Outgoing Server - smtp.mail.yahoo.com

Incoming Port - 993 (requires SSL)

Outgoing Port - 465 (requires SSL/TLS)

Username: full email address (example: bill@yahoo.com)

Password: the password you login to Yahoo with
```

Make sure to identify four mailboxes as special: Drafts, Trash, Sent and Bulk Mail (Junk).

For example, in the left pane under the heading "On My Mac" under the Yahoo account, select the Draft folder. Then on the menu bar select Mailbox > Use This Mailbox For > Drafts.  Do this for the other 3 mailboxes to make sure your mail gets sorted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to override this error is by deleting Yahoo from MacMail box and then add it under 'Other'. You will be prompted to add the new email manually. Once added, go to MacMail to login, **make sure** to use the temporary password provided from the yahoo account (steps below) and not your yahoo password.

Here are the steps:

1. Go to https://login.yahoo.com/account/security? (You may need to sign in to your account again) and click on the app passwords section.
2. Select your non-Yahoo app from the drop down menu and generate an app password for it.
3. Open that app and enter your email and the app password that you just generated to sign in.

Since app passwords are one-time use, you won't need to memorize it or use it in other places.

Answer (score 0):

That error is not due to an incorrect pass, that would be along the lines of, "wrong password email combination", that is just saying its unable to complete the transaction between yahoo, and your MBA. Login to your yahoo, and check if it has denied it login, due to being something like a, suspicious login. If thats not the case then there must be an issue with Yahoo, do you own an email account of another provider you could try? Before ruling it out as an issue with your MBA.

Answer (score 0):

When I was having problems with my Yahoo account on my Macbook Pro, I deleted my Yahoo account and added it back. It seems once a year or so I start having issues with my Yahoo account on my Macbook, either it won't send the emails or I have trouble receiving them. I deleted my Yahoo account on my Mac then I added it back under "Add Account." But, I did not add it under Yahoo account, I added it under "other" account. Typed out my email address and then for password I went to my iphone and hit the "account key" and went to the bottom option "get an app password." That gave me a 16 digit temp password and I was able to add my Yahoo account back to my Macbook without anymore problems. It sent and received emails afterward without any further problems. Perhaps that will work for some of you? I know these constant security measures that we are facing can be a real pain in the behind but it's only because there are so many dishonest people out there causing problems for all of us. Good luck!

Comment: Would this operation preserve the prior downloaded emails (in various boxes)?